# Scrapy rule doesn't work with 'restrict_xpaths'

Tags: python, scrapy

I run my crawler (see below), but it scrapes only page given in 'start_urls'.
Empirically I found out that parameter 'restrict_xpaths' doesn't work.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from ..items import Category
from scrapy import Selector
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class NeoSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'neo'
    allowed_domains = ['neopoliscasa.ru']
    start_urls = ['http://www.neopoliscasa.ru/catalog.html']
    identifier = 1
    subcategory_parent_id = None
    type_parent_id = None
    categories = []
    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                allow='/catalog/[a-z-]+.html',
                restrict_xpaths='//div[contains(@class, "itemTypeIcoon n")]'),
            callback='parse_subcategories'),
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        category_blocks = sel.xpath(
            '//div[@class="rootCatalogItem"]')
        for item in category_blocks:
            category = Category()
            category['category'] = ''.join(item.xpath(
                'h2/a/text()').extract())
            category['id'] = unicode(self.identifier)
            category['parent_id'] = unicode(0)
            self.subcategory_parent_id = self.identifier
            self.identifier += 1
            self.categories.append(category)
            yield category

    def parse_subcategories(self, response):
        #  do anything
        pass
```

How can I fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you should not override the `parse` function when using a `CrawlSpider` as it is stated in the [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules).

To solve your problem rename `parse` into `parse_` for example, or to `parse_start_url` if you want to crawl the data from the first site too.

Then use another `class` in your restriction because there is no entry for `itemTypeIcoon` in the site. And without it you won't get any results.

Perhaps `itemArt` would be a good solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I had very stupid mistakes!